# confirmDialog appears but disappears immediately

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have read similar questions on SA and the Primefaces forum but it did not help. Here is the xhtml:

```
<h:form id="form2" prependId="false">
    <p:remoteCommand name="sendNameClicked" actionListener="#{reportBean.passName}"/>
    <p:remoteCommand name="updateDialog" update=":form3:dialogBox"/>

    <p:commandButton style="display: none" id="displayDialog" type="button" onclick="cd.show(); return false;"/>
</h:form>
<h:form id="form3">
    <p:confirmDialog id ="dialogBox" message= "#{reportBean.getClickedAuthorLaius()}"
                     header="#{reportBean.nameClicked}#{reportBean.authorClicked.mostRecentAffiliation}"
                     widgetVar="cd"
                     severity="info"
                     >
        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-widget"  value="" escape="false" />
        <p:commandButton value="Draw the ring of #{reportBean.obtainFullName()}?" actionListener ="#{controllerBean.prepareNewSearch()}" action ="index?faces-redirect=true" oncomplete="cd.hide();"/>
        <p:commandButton value="No, stay on this page" onclick="cd.hide();" type="button" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
</h:form>
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onclick` is fired before the form submit request is sent. The `update` is performed after form submit response is arrived. So, the confirm dialog is updated after it's been opened and thus get its default appearance again.

You need to open it *after* the update. Use the `oncomplete` attribute instead of `onclick`.

```
<p:commandButton ... oncomplete="cd.show()"/>
```

Comment: the commandButton is triggered by a javascript function which does:  document.getElementById('displayDialog').click(). I adapted your suggestion this way: <p:commandButton style="display: none" id="displayDialog" type="button" onclick="return false;" oncomplete="cd.show();"/> But then nothing happens (the dialog does not open). How can I use the oncomplete while triggering the commandButton with onclick? Thx!

Comment: ok I have opened a new question on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101960/using-oncomplete-in-a-commandbutton-even-when-onclick-is-empty

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the `type="button"`, I didn't expect it here at all. Remove it. Not sure if it would solve your concrete functional requirement. A hidden and dead button is quite strange in this construct, after all. I wonder why you didn't execute the `cd.show()` in the `updateDialog` function itself as that has basically the same effect. Using the `oncomplete` of `<p:remoteCommand>` itself would make much more sense based on the code and information provided so far.

Comment: do you ever visit the Netherlands? I owe you so many rounds of beers.

Comment: You're welcome :) I do currently not have any plans to visit it.