# using "oncomplete" in a commandButton even when onclick is empty?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

In a jsf 2 project, a commandButton with id "displayDialog" is hidden. It gets triggered by a javascript function:

```
 document.getElementById('displayDialog').click();
```

The thing is, I need the click action to be performed at the stage of "oncomplete", not "onclick" (for a reason explained by @BalusC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100749/confirmdialog-appears-but-disappears-immediately)).

I tried to do:

```
    <p:commandButton style="display: none" id="displayDialog" type="button" onclick="" oncomplete="cd.show();"/>
```

or

```
    <p:commandButton style="display: none" id="displayDialog" type="button" onclick="return false;" oncomplete="cd.show();"/>
```

but in both cases cd.show() is not actioned. How should this be done?

(Should I just add a dummy action in the onclick attribute? If so which one?)

Comment: The `oncomplete` method will be invoked after the ajax request has been executed. In both examples, no ajax request is executed, thus your `oncomplete` method will never run. Note that the second example is the worst thing you can do ever because the button will never submit a request.

Comment: thx! What kind of dummy / fake / ineffective ajax request could I put in the onclick method, in order to trigger the oncomplete method afterwards?

Comment: Do not even write a `onclick` method. Just write the `oncomplete`.

Comment: Try <a4j:commandButton> in a4j library.

Answer (score 2):

The `oncomplete` method is invoked after an ajax request, and when you say that `type="button"`, no ajax request will be made.

That said, just remove the `type="button"` parameter and you don't have to implement `onclick` at all.

```
<p:commandButton style="display: none" 
                 id="displayDialog" 
                 oncomplete="cd.show();"/>
```

---

But, do you really need the button to be called from a JavaScript function? If there is another component making the *first* request, can't you just implement the `oncomplete` method of *that* component?

In your code, the `p:commandButton` has no action at all, then *why* do you need to wait for the action to be completed? Are you submitting a form or something?

Maybe if you explain exactly what you want to do, we can think of a better way to do it.